# getting error in "invert" command discord.py rewrite v1.3.4

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, discord, discord.py

Here is my code -

```
@client.command()
async def invert(ctx, user: discord.User = None):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(str(user.avatar_url)) as response:
            image_bytes = await response.read()

    img = Image.open(image_bytes)
    await ImageOps.invert(img)

    with io.BytesIO() as my_image:
        img.save(my_image,
                 'PNG')
        my_image.seek(0)
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=my_image,
                                         filename="image.png"))
```

And it gives the error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\k\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\k\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\k\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 6: invalid continuation byte
```

I have never used PIL before, so any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert the image in this way:

```py
img = Image.open(image_bytes).convert("RGBA")
```